# Como criar uma rota abstrata com controller global para seus filhos no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

Estou criando uma aplicação onde vou criar algo semelhante a um "wizzard" do windows forms e para isso estou usando um roteamento da seguinte forma:

```
.state("vendaOrcamento", {
  url: "/vendaOrcamento",
  abstract:true,
  templateUrl: "templates/comercial/vendaOrcamento.html"
})
.state('vendaOrcamento.cliente', {
  url: "/cliente",
  views: {
    'tab-cliente': {
      templateUrl: "templates/comercial/vendaOrcamento/1cliente.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('vendaOrcamento.produtos', {
  url: "/produtos",
    views: {
      'tab-produtos': {
        templateUrl: "templates/comercial/vendaOrcamento/2produtos.html"
      }
    }
  })
```

Eu preciso que tanto para o filho **cliente** quanto para o filho **produtos** exista um objeto `vendaOrcamento` global, assim independente de qual filho eu estiver, eu sempre estarei trabalhando com o mesmo objeto sem perder os dados já tratados anteriormente, basicamente preciso disso:

```
$scope.vendaOrcamento = {
  cliente : {},
  produtos : {}
}
```

O meu problema é que não entendi muito bem como posso trabalhar assim, eu cheguei a tentar criar um `Controller` diretamente na **view** pai(vendaOrcamento) mas não deu muito certo... alguém pode me dar uma luz por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu dei uma boa lida no que o @GuilhermeSantos disse e era uma opção bem funcional, mas acabei optando por uma **value** porque mesmo que a pessoa comece a edição mas saia dessa tela eu tenho como ao voltar pra mesma continuar de onde parou

Comment: De preferência para o uso de [`controller as`](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar utilizar um factory para compartilhar dados entre controllers.

Existe bastante conteúdo pronto, só pesquisar algo como "[share data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)".